# uitableview with alphabetical index (swift)

Tags: swift

```
var sections : [(index: Int, length :Int, title: String)] = Array()
var array = ["Moscow", "Saint Petersburg", "Novosibirsk", "Novosibirsk", "Nizhny Novgorod", "Samara", "Omsk", "Kiyv", "Odessa", "Donetsk", "Harkiv", "Lviv", "Uzhgorod", "Zhytomyr", "Luhansk", "Mikolayv", "Kherson", "Germany", "Berlin", "Hamburg", "Munich", "Cologne", "Frankfurt", "Stuttgart", "Düsseldorf", "Dortmund", "Essen", "Bremen", "Abilene", "Akron", "Albuquerque", "Alexandria", "Allentown", "Amarillo", "Anaheim", "Anchorage", "Ann Arbor", "Antioch", "Arlington", "Arvada", "Athens", "Atlanta", "Augusta", "Aurora", "Austin", "Bakersfield", "Baltimore", "Baton Rouge", "Beaumont", "Bellevue", "Berkeley", "Billings", "Birmingham", "Boise", "Boston", "Boulder", "Bridgeport", "Broken Arrow", "Brownsville", "Buffalo", "Burbank", "Cambridge", "Cape Coral", "Carlsbad", "Carrollton", "Cary", "Cedar Rapids", "Centennial", "Chandler", "Charleston", "Charlotte", "Chattanooga", "Chesapeake", "Chicago", "Chula Vista", "Cincinnati", "Clarksville", "Clearwater", "Cleveland", "College Station", "Colorado Springs", "Columbia", "Columbus", "Concord", "Coral Springs", "Corona", "Corpus Christi", "Costa Mesa", "Dallas", "Daly City", "Davenport", "Dayton", "Denton", "Denver", "Des Moines", "Detroit", "Downey", "Durham", "Edison", "El Cajon", "El Monte", "El Paso", "Elgin", "Elizabeth", "Elk Grove", "Erie", "Escondido", "Eugene", "Evansville", "Everett", "Fairfield", "Fargo", "Fayetteville", "Fontana", "Fort Collins", "Fort Lauderdale", "Fort Wayne", "Fort Worth", "Fremont", "Fresno", "Frisco", "Fullerton", "Gainesville", "Garden Grove", "Garland", "Gilbert", "Glendale", "Grand Prairie", "Grand Rapids", "Green Bay", "Greensboro", "Gresham", "Hampton", "Hartford", "Hayward", "Henderson", "Hialeah", "High Point", "Hollywood", "Honolulu", "Houston", "Huntington Beach", "Huntsville", "Independence", "Indianapolis", "Inglewood", "Irvine", "Irving", "Jackson", "Jacksonville", "Jersey City", "Joliet", "Kansas City", "Kent", "Killeen", "Knoxville", "Lafayette", "Lakeland", "Lakewood", "Lancaster", "Lansing", "Laredo", "Las Cruces", "Las Vegas", "Lewisville", "Lexington", "Lincoln", "Little Rock", "Long Beach", "Los Angeles", "Louisville", "Lowell", "Lubbock", "Madison", "Manchester", "McAllen", "McKinney", "Memphis", "Mesa", "Mesquite", "Miami", "Miami Gardens", "Midland", "Milwaukee", "Minneapolis", "Miramar", "Mobile", "Modesto", "Montgomery", "Moreno Valley", "Murfreesboro", "Murrieta", "Naperville", "Nashville", "New Haven", "New Orleans", "New York", "Newark", "Newport News", "Norfolk", "Norman", "North Charleston", "North Las Vegas", "Norwalk", "Oakland", "Oceanside", "Oklahoma City", "Olathe", "Omaha", "Ontario", "Orange", "Orlando", "Overland Park", "Oxnard", "Palm Bay", "Palmdale", "Pasadena", "Paterson", "Pearland", "Pembroke Pines", "Peoria", "Peoria", "Philadelphia", "Phoenix", "Pittsburgh", "Plano", "Pomona", "Pompano Beach", "Port St. Lucie", "Portland", "Providence", "Provo", "Pueblo", "Raleigh", "Rancho Cucamonga", "Reno", "Rialto", "Richardson", "Richmond", "Riverside", "Rochester", "Rockford", "Roseville", "Round Rock", "Sacramento", "Saint Paul", "Salem", "Salinas", "Salt Lake City", "San Antonio", "San Bernardino", "San Diego", "San Francisco", "San Jose", "San Mateo", "Santa Ana", "Santa Clara", "Santa Clarita", "Santa Maria", "Santa Rosa", "Savannah", "Scottsdale", "Seattle", "Shreveport", "Simi Valley", "Sioux Falls", "South Bend", "Spokane", "Springfield", "St. Louis", "St. Petersburg", "Stamford", "Sterling Heights", "Stockton", "Sunnyvale", "Surprise", "Syracuse", "Tacoma", "Tallahassee", "Tampa", "Temecula", "Tempe", "Thornton", "Thousand Oaks", "Toledo", "Topeka", "Torrance", "Tucson", "Tulsa", "Tyler", "Vallejo", "Vancouver", "Ventura", "Victorville", "Virginia Beach", "Visalia", "Waco", "Warren", "Washington", "Waterbury", "West Covina", "West Jordan", "West Palm Beach", "West Valley City", "Westminster", "Wichita", "Wichita Falls", "Wilmington", "Winston–Salem", "Woodbridge", "Worcester", "Yonkers", "York"]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    array.sort { $0 < $1 }
    var index = 0;

    for ( var i = 0; i < array.count; i++ ) {

        let commonPrefix = array[i].commonPrefixWithString(array[index], options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch)

        if (countElements(commonPrefix) == 0 ) {

            let string = array[index].uppercaseString;

            let firstCharacter = string[string.startIndex]

            let title = "\(firstCharacter)"

            let newSection = (index: index, length: i - index, title: title)

            sections.append(newSection)

            index = i;

        }

    }
}


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return sections.count

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return sections[section].length

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell;

    cell.textLabel?.text = array[sections[indexPath.section].index + indexPath.row]

    return cell

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String {

    return sections[section].title

}

override func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [AnyObject]! {

    return sections.map { $0.title }

}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, atIndex index: Int) -> Int {

    return index

}
```

I found an example from [this](http://www.edumobile.org/ios/indexed-table-views-in-swift/#comment-32602) website. However, I don't know what is `countElements()` in the if case. 
He didn't declare it. Can anyone help?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
if (commonPrefix.characters.count == 0 )
```

Common prefix is deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

For those that want an updated version for Swfit 4+

```
                      var index = 0;
          // for ( var i = 0; i < array.count; i++ )
        for i in 0..<(array.count - 1)
           {

               let commonPrefix = array[i].commonPrefix(with: array[index], options: .caseInsensitive)


            if (commonPrefix.count == 0 ) {

                   let string = array[index].uppercased();

                   let firstCharacter = string[string.startIndex]

                   let title = "\(firstCharacter)"

                   let newSection = (index: index, length: i - index, title: title)

                   sections.append(newSection)

                   index = i;

               }

           }
```

Although I still can't get it to work 100% I believe my for in may not be correct